# How to exclude datasets with no data on datahub.io search?

Tags: ckan

datahub.io contain many datasets, but some of it marked *This dataset has no data*

For example http://datahub.io/dataset/industrial-production-and-turnover-indices or http://datahub.io/dataset/esis

How to exclude datasets with no data on datahub.io search?

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of hacky, but you can use a search engine like Google to search within a domain, and then exclude certain strings that indicate the dataset has no data.

[image]

**[LINK](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=ESIS+-%22This+dataset+has+no+data%22+site:datahub.io%2Fdataset%2F+-related+-activity+-tags)**

In this case, the search includes pages with:

- *ESIS* (but can be left blank)
- *site:datahub.io/dataset/* (include the dataset folder because otherwise, the "no data" message comes in various languages)

Excludes pages with:

- *"This dataset has no data, why not add some?"*
- *related* (non-data folder)
- *activity* (non-data folder)

In the results list, you'll see the ESIS page you mentioned is not included. You can removed ESIS and replace it with the term you want to search, or leave it blank to search all datasets.